# matplotlib new line co-ordinates points after rotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a 2d line (x1, y1) -> (x2,y2) and rotating by angle theta in matplotlib using Affine2D.rotate_deg_around.

```
start = (120, 0)
ht = 100
coords = currentAxis.transData.transform([start[0],start[1]])
trans1 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0],coords[1], 45)
line1 = lines.Line2D([start[0], start[0]], [start[1], ht+start[1]], color='r', linewidth=2)
line1.set_transform(currentAxis.transData + trans1)
currentAxis.add_line(line1)
```

Now (x2, y2) wont be (120, 100) after rotation. I need to find new (x2, y2) after rotation.

Answer (score 2):

The matplotlib transformation functions might not be the most comfortable solution here.

Since you are rotating and translating your original data points you might be better off using a "common" 3 x 3 rotation matrix and a separate translation. Or a 4 x 4 matrix with holds both, rotation and translation.

Check the function `rotation_matrix(angle, direction, point=None)` from 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html

This one returns a 4 x 4 matrix for rotation, but you can set the upper three components in the right column with the translation.

It might look scary at first :)
But once you get used to it is a very handy tool for that sort of things.

A bit more info

http://www.dirsig.org/docs/new/affine.html

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Comment: I have already tried it. It gives me those values passed while create a line i.e.[120, 120] and [0, 100]. I need transformed points.

Answer (score 1):

You are first transforming to display coordinates and then rotate about the point in display coordinates. However, what I think you want to do is to perform the rotation in data coordinates and then transform to display coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.lines as lines
start = (120, 0)
ht = 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

trans1 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(start[0],start[1], 45)
line1 = lines.Line2D([start[0], start[0]], [start[1], ht+start[1]], color='r', linewidth=2)
line1.set_transform(trans1 + ax.transData) 
ax.add_line(line1)

ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The transform can then also be used to obtain the rotated coordinates

```
newpoint = trans1.transform([start[0], ht+start[1]])
# in this case newpoint would be [ 49.28932188  70.71067812]
```

Comment: Ok..But how do I get new co-ordinates of (x2,y2) which without transformation was (120,100). Need these new points after transformation

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the new points"? The line does have the new coordinates, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it has new points which is visually seen. But I need new transformed points. I need it to draw another line.

Comment: you can use `trans1` to get the coordinates, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get new co ordinates after transformation. So did the following.

1. shifted axis and Rotated around point of rotation.
2. dot product( matrix of above operation, point which need to be transformed(P))
3. Result of dot product gives new co-ordinates of P after rotation

   ```
   trans1 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(120, 100, 45)
   txn = np.dot(trans1.get_matrix(), [120, 200, 1])
   line1 = lines.Line2D([120, txn[0]], [100, txn[1]], color='r', linewidth=line_width)
   currentAxis.add_line(line1)
   ```